# Как перехватить Spring транзакцию перед commit?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jpa, transaction, spring-aop

Возникла необходимость в перехвате транзакции перед commit, чтобы добавлять системную информацию в БД. Особенность состоит в том, что это должно происходить из подключаемого jar.

Пробовал такие варианты как:

1) использование собственного аспекта, которые отрабатывает после методов с аннотацией @Transactional. 
Выглядит это так:

```
@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {

@Autowired
private AuditRepository auditRepository;

public AuditAspect(AuditRepository auditRepository) {
    this.auditRepository = auditRepository;
}

@AfterReturning("@annotation(javax.transaction.Transactional)")
public void saveApplicationParameters(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(IgnoreAudit.class)) {
        AuditInfo auditInfo = ignoreAudit();
        auditRepository.save(auditInfo);
    }
}
```

Данный способ не подходит, так как существуют реализации, например использование Spring Data, для которых аннотация Transactional навешивается под капотом, а так как Spring Data реализована через proxy, то кастомный аспект не видит аннотацию и соотв. не срабатывает.

2) использование TransactionSynchronizationManager, но сложность состоит в том, что TransactionSynchronization необходимо добавлять в скопе транзакции.

3) использвание TransactionProxyFactoryBean, для того чтобы добавить кастомный интерсептор (наподобии TransactionInterceptor), который будет отрабатывать после TransactionInterceptor. Но возникла проблема с добавление этого интерсептора.

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами. Буду рад любому ответу)

Comment: Ничего из [этого](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) не подойдёт?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev к сожалению, не подходит, необходимо реализовать подход, который не будет затрагивать реализацию бизнес функционалу
использование Spring AOP здесь больше подходит, но проблему с использование AOP, я описал в пункте 1

Comment: В спринге постоянно внутри контекста порождаются какие то ивенты. И, возможно, коммит транзакции - это тоже событие, на которое можно навесить слушателя.
Вот тут https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application даже есть пример: аннотация @TransactionalEventListener с синхронизацией на фазе BEFORE_COMMIT. Я не вчитывался, но выглядит как то, что решит вашу проблему

Comment: По идее нужно переопределить (отнаследовать) нужный PostProcessor, который делает логику аннотации @ Transactional. Сделать его @ primary bean, чтобы использовался он, а не стандартный. И добавить туда любую логику, которая отвечает за транзакцию. Что-то типа TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor или PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor